# Erlang: Splitting consult() return value into sublists

Tags: list, erlang, tuples

I have a calls.txt:

{john, [jill,joe,bob]}.

{jill, [bob,joe,bob]}.

{sue, [jill,jill,jill,bob,jill]}.

{bob, [john]}.

{joe, [sue]}.

I have a function read()

```
read() -> 
    List = file:consult("calls.txt"),
```

calling read() returns a list of 5 tuples

```
{ok,[{john,[jill,joe,bob]},
 {jill,[bob,joe,bob]},
 {sue,[jill,jill,jill,bob,jill]},
 {bob,[john]},
 {joe,[sue]}]}
```

I want to bind each of the tuples to a variable (X1,X2,X3,X4,X5)

I've tried splitting the list into 4 heads and a tail

```
 read() -> 
List = file:consult("calls.txt"),
[X1,X2,X3,X4|X5] = List.
```

however, it gives me the error:

```
** exception error: no match of right hand side value
```

How do I split the returned list from consult() into 5 tuples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value is `{ok, <list of 5 elements>}` so the pattern you need to use is `{ok, [X1, X2, X3, X4, X5]}`:

```
{ok, [X1, X2, X3, X4, X5]} = file:consult("calls.txt").
```